# SQL Query Assistnace

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

This query gives all the templateId that are assigned to product id less than 5 and that's the expected output. But we wanted to achieve that without using the sub query in the where clause (Highlighted in red).

If I just remove the subquery then the output will be all the templateId from templateproduct table. we don't wnat that. what we want is the template id that's only assigned from product 1 to 5. so our expected output is:

100
102

today we are acheiving this using additional subquery, we wanted to acheive the same result without using the subquery.

we are using sql 2008

Comment: Please don't use images for you data. They're hard to build demos from. Instead paste the data in directly. If you want it foramted nicely try  [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a LEFT JOIN in place of a subquery, and check for NULL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tp.template_id
FROM templateproduct tp
LEFT JOIN templateproduct tp2
  ON tp.template_id = tp2.template_id AND tp2.prod_id IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
WHERE tp.prod_id < 5
  AND tp2.template_id IS NULL
```

You can do a similar thing using GROUP BY and check that there are 0 matching templates linking to the excluded product ids:

```
SELECT tp.template_id
FROM templateproduct tp
LEFT JOIN templateproduct tp2
  ON tp.template_id = tp2.template_id AND tp2.prod_id IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
WHERE tp.prod_id < 5
GROUP BY tp.template_id
HAVING COUNT(tp2.template_id) = 0
```

Depending on your data and indexing, this may or may not be more efficient than a subquery - I suggest you try it out.  In any event, there is no reason to have any INNER JOINs at all to get the results you are seeking:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tp.template_id
FROM templateproduct tp
WHERE tp.prod_id < 5
  AND tp.template_id NOT IN (
    SELECT tp2.template_id FROM templateproduct tp2 WHERE tp2.prod_id IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
  )
```

Try these out and see which performs better for you.  And of course, check the query plan to see why this is.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your where clause should be **tp.prod_id <= 5**

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about the layout of your columns but something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT
    TemplateID,
    --Other fields here
FROM
    Product pr INNER JOIN TemplateProduct tp on pr.prod_id = tp.prod_id 
        INNER JOIN Template tr on tp.templateID = tr.templateID AND tr.prod_id = pr.prod_id
WHERE
    tp.prod_id < 5
```

Comment: how different this is from the query I pasted? if I just remove the subquery then the output will be all the templateid's.